# Does Django try to translate template variables?

Tags: django, internationalization, django-templates, django-1.6

I have the following code in my template:

```
{% blocktrans %}Hello, {{ user.username }}!{% endblocktrans %}
```

This appears on my site as:

> Hello, !

I am sure that the variable is populated (because it shows up correctly if I remove the `blocktrans` tag), so my question is: does Django attempt to translate variables too? A working code for me was:

```
{% blocktrans with username=user.username %}Hello, {{ username }}!{% endblocktrans %}
```

However, in the Django core, in one of the templates, there's this code:

```
{% blocktrans %}You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.{% endblocktrans %}
```

So I think this should work, right? Is there an obvious mistake I'm not noticing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have variables in `blocktrans` blocks, but you can't access object attributes, as you are attempting with `user.username`. You need to bind those to local variables, as per [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag):

```
{% blocktrans with amount=article.price %}
That will cost $ {{ amount }}.
{% endblocktrans %}
```

**EDIT**: Sorry, I just noticed I misread your question, you do mention local binding. But then that's your answer. The example you show from django core uses `site_name`, not `site.name`.

Comment: I see. Didn't know you can't use properties. At some point I suspected that was the problem, but wasn't sure.